facebook messenger bot connected to page but empty subscription
I want to connect my Messenger Bot to other FacebookPage, I have url https://www.facebook.com/v20.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://XXXXXX/signin-facebook&state=123t23tg23t32t23t2abc&scope=pages_messaging
I am using other Fb account, which own the Page, then open above link, then choose this page on the Dialog => accept permission.
After that, in the Facebook developer portal, I see this page were linked to my App, but this show empty subscriptions, but I need messages and messages_postback for receive the message.
NOTE:

My Application were reviewed pages_messaging permission and go live since a month.
After accept permission on the Link I gived above, I got the code from the redirect URI, then:


I used https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/oauth/access_token to get the token from this code.
I used https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/me/accounts to get the PageID + PageAccessToken from the accessToken above (1)
After that, I tried to open this page, then send message, but no response from my bot, it seem the page were linked to my Application, but empty subscriptions cause the bot can not get the message


Can someone guide me to know what am I wrong here? THanks so much
